# Safari, Chrome runs code in window.load before page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have some html that looks like this:

```
 <div class="nmMap-wrapper">
        <div id="draggable" class="nmMap-image">
            <div class="nmMap"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and on the `"nmMap"` I have a background image set in the css.

I then have a javascript loading the background image, appdending it as a image, and then getting the width and height, and alerting all the diffirent variables.

The script looks like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
sceneConstructor();
});

function sceneConstructor() {

    var bgHeight;
    var bgWidth;
    var bgAspectRatio;

    function init() {

        getBgSize();
        alertRatio();

    }

    function getBgSize() {

        var bgsrc = jQuery('.nmMap').css('background-image')
            .replace('url("', '')
            .replace('url(', '')
            .replace('")', '')
            .replace(')', '')
            .replace('"', '')
            .replace("'", '');

        var bgImg = jQuery('<img />');

        //bgImg.hide();

        jQuery('.nmMap').append(bgImg);

        bgImg.attr('src', bgsrc);

        bgImg.bind('load', function() {
            var width = jQuery(this).width();
            var height = jQuery(this).height();
            alert('first height' + height);
            setAspectRatio(width, height);
        });

    }

    function setAspectRatio(width, height) {
        alert('second height: ' + height);
        bgHeight = height;
        bgWidth = width;
        bgAspectRatio = bgWidth / bgHeight;
        alert('trejde: ' + bgHeight);
        jQuery('.nmMap').addClass('ration');
    }

    function alertRatio() {
        alert('bgheight ' + bgHeight);
        alert('bgwidth ' + bgWidth);
        alert('bgheight ' + bgHeight);
        alert('bgaspect ' + bgAspectRatio);
    }

    init();

}
```

All this working in firefox, except that the first alert in `alertRatio()` always gets undefined. But in safari, chrome, and IE, it's like `alertRaiom()` is being run first, and because of that all the alerts are undefined.

Can someone help and tell me whats going on?

Comment: `jQuery().load()` is a function that loads data from a remote URL. `jQuery.ready()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: that did not work. the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

try the default .ready from jquery.

this code load after the dom is loaded.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
sceneConstructor();
}):
```

you can also

```
jQuery( window ).ready(function() {
sceneConstructor();
}):
```

source: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: none off does work, it still result in alertRatio(); being run first.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you `bind()` the event listener before you set the image's `src` attribute?